# Server-side rendering always returns an error "Target container is not a DOM element"

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, ejs

I'm stuggling with server-side rendering and univeral routing in my React app.
I'm tryi"Target container is not a DOM element" error. Not sure where to look for cause of the problem.

Here is my main server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var routes = require('./routes/index.js');
var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', routes); //<------


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Here is my router I'm using on marked line:

```
var express = require('express');
var requestHandler = require('../public/requestHandler.bundle.js');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const data = requestHandler(req.location);
  console.log(data);
  if (data.context.status === 404) {
      res.status(404);
    }
    if (data.context.status === 302) {
      return res.redirect(302, data.context.url);
    }
    res.render('index', {initialState: data.initialState, reactComponent: data.reactComponent });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Inside my router I'm using compiled requestHandler:

```
import React from 'react';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../client/reducers';
import routes from '../client/components/routes';
import axios from 'axios';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

function requestHandler(location){
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/books')
    .then(function(response) {
    const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);
    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers, {
      "books": {
        "books": response.data
      }
    })
    const context = {};

    const reactComponent = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={location} context={context}>
          {renderRoutes(routes)}
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
    return{reactComponent:reactComponent, initialState:store.getState(), context:context}
  })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('#Initial Server-side rendering error', err);
      })
}

module.exports = requestHandler;
```

And finally this is my index.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>html from the server</TITLE>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-S7YMK1xjUjSpEnF4P8hPUcgjXYLZKK3fQW1j5ObLSl787II9p8RO9XUGehRmKsxd" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bundle.css" type="text/css"  />
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV id="app"><%-reactComponent-%></DIV>
    <script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__=<%- initialState -%></script>
    <SCRIPT src="./bundle.js"></SCRIPT>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I checked everything countless times and everything looks fine for me....
Not for the browser:[console with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aez59.png)

If you need more information just ask. I'm not sure wchich parts of my code could be problematic